# Prove the following determinant identities.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Definition of determinant:

$$\det{A} := \sum_{i}^{n} (-1)^{i+j}A_{ji}\det{M_{ji}}$$
where $M_{ij}$ is the minor with respect to $A_{ji}$ for some row $j$ in $A$.

Show

$$\det{A} = \det{A^T}$$

$$(\det{A})^* = \det{A^*},$$

where $$A^* = \overline{{A^T}}$$ is the complex conjugate of the matrix.

Comment: A proof of the properties given requires the use of a particular definition. There are many equivalent definitions, and not every introductory course uses the same one. You claim to use "the standard definition", but its not possible for us to know which definition that is. For instance and incomplete list of definitions can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Definition .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix. I will use the following as the definition of the determinant,

$$ \det(A) = \frac{1}{n!} \sum \epsilon_{i_1 \dots i_n} \epsilon_{j_1\dots j_n} A_{i_1 j_1}A_{i_2 j_2} \cdots A_{i_n j_n}, $$

where the $i_k$ and $j_k$ are each summed from $1$ to $n$.

---

Now we consider the first property $\det(A^T) = \det(A)$.

$$ \det(A^T) = \frac{1}{n!} \sum \epsilon_{i_1 \dots i_n} \epsilon_{j_1\dots j_n} A^T_{i_1 j_1}A^T_{i_2 j_2} \cdots A^T_{i_n j_n}, $$

We first use the fact that $A^T_{ij} = A_{ji}$.

$$ = \frac{1}{n!} \sum \epsilon_{i_1 \dots i_n} \epsilon_{j_1\dots j_n} A_{j_1 i_1}A_{j_2 i_2} \cdots A_{j_n i_n}, $$

The $i_k$ are dummy indices and so we can change their label without changing the value of the summation. Replace each $i_k$ with the label $s_k$.

$$ = \frac{1}{n!} \sum \epsilon_{s_1 \dots s_n} \epsilon_{j_1\dots j_n} A_{j_1 s_1}A_{j_2 s_2} \cdots A_{j_n s_n}, $$

Now change each label $j_k$ to have the label $i_k$.

$$ = \frac{1}{n!} \sum \epsilon_{s_1 \dots s_n} \epsilon_{i_1\dots i_n} A_{i_1 s_1}A_{i_2 s_2} \cdots A_{i_n s_n}, $$

Now change each label $s_k$ to have the label $j_k$.

$$ = \frac{1}{n!} \sum \epsilon_{j_1 \dots j_n} \epsilon_{i_1\dots i_n} A_{i_1 j_1}A_{i_2 j_2} \cdots A_{i_n j_n}, $$

Now use the commutative property of real numbers to exchange the order of 
the levi-cevita symbols.

$$ = \frac{1}{n!} \sum  \epsilon_{i_1\dots i_n} \epsilon_{j_1 \dots j_n} A_{i_1 j_1}A_{i_2 j_2} \cdots A_{i_n j_n} = \det(A), $$

---

Comment: I started this incomplete answer before you updated your question to include a definition. Let me know if you find this answer useful, if you do not then I will delete it.

Comment: Hey, Spencer. It is difficult for me to understand your proof. I have never encountered your definition of the determinant. For example, I have no clue what the lower case epsilons signify. Regardless, thank you for your consideration. Feel free to leave it for others who may see the post. It may be helpful for someone else.